# Isn't a rotation just a sum of many translations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, symmetry, rotation, galilean-relativity

If the world is (really or hypothetically) made of elementary, point-particles, then it's there such a thing as rotation?

Point particles by definition can't rotate around themselves. The only possible movement they have, is translation.

If a point particle rotates around another, it really isn't rotating. It's just *translating* around it.

In other words, any rotation can be described as a translation. If I rotate a pencil, what's happening is that all the elementary particles of the pencil are *translating* in a specific way. There is no pencil, and there is no rotation. Only particles, and their translations. (Or viceversa!)

What I'm saying is I don't think rotation and translation are independent transformations. They are the same, expressed in two different ways. Or in other words, a rotation is the sum of the translations of its particles.

Or is there something else about rotation that I'm ignoring? Is rotating a pencil not exactly the same as translating every elementary particle in it in a specific way (without ever needing to "rotate" anything)?

Comment: Infinitesimal rotation amounts to an infinitesimal translation (locally). The problem is the global effect and the group structure.

Comment: "If a point particle rotates around another, it really isn't rotating. It's just translating around it"?. No. Translational motion is motion in which all points of a moving body move uniformly in the same line or direction.

Comment: The world is not made of point-particles. The world is made of quantum fields that the standard theory describes with a point-like commutator. The jury is still out on whether that is the correct description or not. Even so a single quantum does not have to behave trivially under rotation. Spins and magnetic moments certainly don't and they are quite physical.

Comment: @BobD Allright, then with that definition the question would be answered. Is there a term for "translating only *one* point of the body"? So I'll edit the question to use that term instead

Comment: @JuanPerez I'm not sure what you mean by ""translating only one point of the body". Translation is linear motion, whether it be a particle or point on an extended body. That said, a particle can be both translating and rotating about some other point.

Comment: @BobD If a single point moves in a *curved* path, it is not possible to describe its movement as a sequence of infinitecimal translations in varying directions? Without needing to use rotations at all? That's what I'm asking: if it is possible to describe any movement of points exclusively with translations.

Comment: @JuanPerez But technically, you can also define translation as infinite series of rotations about arbitrary points along in a linear path (think about sine wave). So what ? The thing that you can define some sort of edge-case scenario, does not show that these are not different symmetries. It's like you would want to say, that we don't need a circle concept, because we can approximate it with a polygon with infinite amount of edges :-)

Answer (score 4):

One major issue with this argument is that classical point particles do not exist. Actual fundamental particles are quantum mechanical, and they can and do rotate. Not in the sense of a classical rigid body rotation, but in the sense of a symmetry group.

Rotation and translation are fundamentally different because they are different symmetries and have different generators. Perhaps more importantly, they lead to different conserved quantities. Rotation leads to the conservation of angular momentum and translation leads to the conservation of linear momentum. Both are separately conserved in actual elementary particle interactions.

The world is not classical. There may be other weaknesses of the argument that make it problematic for a hypothetical classical point particle containing world, but it definitely does not represent the actual world.

Answer (score 2):

Rotating a rigid body in 3D around and axis $\mathbf{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)^\top$ by an angle $\theta$ can be described by the multiplication of every point $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^\top$ in the body with the matrix
$$
R=\exp(\theta\,U)\,,\quad U=\begin{pmatrix}0&-u_3&u_2\\u_3&0&-u_1\\-u_2&u_1&0\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
For small $\delta\theta$ we have a small rotation
$$
R\approx 1+\delta\theta\,U\,,
$$
or
$$
R\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}+\delta\theta\,\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{x}\,.
$$
In other words, $\mathbf{x}$ is translated by the small vector $\delta\theta\,\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{x}$ that is perpendicular to $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{x}\,.$

If you iterate this process you can obviously view a rotation by $\theta$ as a series of small translations whose directions are gradually changing.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for making a full and **ideal** rotation, (aka _circle_) one needs to perform infinite amount of infinitesimal translations, which looks like some sort of indeterminate form or at least sounds like less physically valid.

Comment: Of course . If we were to abandon proper rotations entirely from physics we would litteraly blind one of our eyes and miss at least one very important conservation law as @Dale has poined out in his answer. I wanted to show OP that the question was justified. But this is as good as it gets.